# Ember's App.reset and model.rollback causing buggy behavior during tests

Tags: testing, ember.js, qunit

Before each test, I reset the application like so:

```
QUnit.testStart = ->
  App.reset()
```

For the most part, this works great. However, in one of my routes I've defined a rollback:

```
App.ProjectsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend

  model: ->
    @store.createRecord('project')
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set('content', model)
  deactivate: ->
    @get('controller.model').rollback()
```

When the rollback is present, a number of seemingly unrelated integration and route tests fail. If I comment out the rollback, these other tests pass as expected. Alternatively, I can comment `App.reset()`, and everything works as expected. So why aren't these two playing nicely? As my test suite grows, I'll need to be able to call `App.reset()` without it breaking things.

Comment: App reset resets the ember app, not the store.  Nor records in the store.  Additionally ember data methods are generally asynchronous, meaning you may or may not be finished when you switch tasks

Comment: So perhaps what's happening is that the rollback has a pending callback, and after the App resets, that callback completes, causing buggy behavior?

Comment: I'd guess somewhere along those lines, some asynchronous issues leaking into the wrong area of code.

Comment: Do you know of a helper method that forces any pending promises to resolve before executing the next line?

Comment: Ember keeps track of its promises during testing, but whether or not it keeps track of external libraries promises I'm not sure (I'd doubt it, but if I remember correctly they blast away the default implementation for testing mode so as to keep track of it.  I'd have to play with it a bit.  The next step might be isolating a reproducible implementation in a jsbin.

Comment: This discussion got me thinking about the `andThen` helper method, which actually does the trick.

Comment: w00t, glad to hear you found a solution, will you add it to the answer and accept it when you can?